failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)
     Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0.aar -> core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-27.1.1.aar -> support-compat-27.1.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1)

i am react native developer was trying to run the app after upgrading the react native library in the project from '0.71.8' to '0.75.1'
i have little experience in android developement. i am not able to understand the error here
i have been following this guide to updating the project :- Update React native

I was able to get a build working by re-adding Jetifier
in android/gradle.properties add the following
    android.enableJetifier=true

I believe this is required when using dependencies that haven't updated their native code to support AndroidX. I couldn't find the rationale for why this has been removed in React Native if anyone knows, please also post an answer on this question.
